# How to write a simple toggle button?

Tags: android, eclipse

Can anyone help me to write code for a toggle button(1 is enough) with simple function (a text or message eg: on, off  will pop out once the toggle button is clicked)?

As simple as possible because I just started this a couple of days ago and my app keeps crashing.

Or maybe someone can catch my errors?

```
package com.example.ledfinal;

import com.example.ledfinal.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivityled extends Activity {

    ToggleButton button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activityled);

    button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (button.isChecked()){
                System.out.println("On");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Off");
            }

        }


    });
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activityled, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: can you what is the error in logcat

Comment: without stacktrace we can't help. But I see some ability to improvement. You can use setOnCheckedChangeListener instead of setOnClickListener.

Comment: sorry, what is a stacktrace?
There has no syntax error in the program, but my program just crashed. I'm predict it might have some logical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code about simple toggleButton

the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
     >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

values/string.xml add this line

```
 <string name="btn">see option</string>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ToggleButton toggleButton;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
               result.append("toggleButton1 : ").append(toggleButton.getText());


               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

      }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry bro, can you add some "if", "else" statement in it?